# Is redirection a valid strategy for an API Gateway?

Tags: redirect, reverse-proxy, api-gateway

I read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/architect-microservice-container-applications/direct-client-to-microservice-communication-versus-the-api-gateway-pattern) about the API Gateway pattern. I realize that API Gateways typically serve as **reverse proxies**, but this forces a bottleneck situation. If all requests to an application's public services go through a single gateway, or even a single load balancer across multiple replicas of a gateway (perhaps a hardware load balancer which can handle large amounts of bandwidth more easily than an API gateway), then that single access point is the bottleneck.

I also understand that it is a wide bottleneck, as it simply has to deliver messages in proxy, as the gateways and load balancers themselves are not responsible for any processing or querying. However, imagining a very large application with many users, one would require extremely powerful hardware to not notice the massive bandwidth traveling over the gateway or load balancer, given that every request to every microservice exposed by the gateway travels through that single access point.

If the API gateway **instead simply redirected the client** to publicly exposed microservices (sort of like a custom DNS lookup), the hardware requirements would be much lower. This is because the messages traveling to and from the API Gateway would be very small, the requests consisting only of a microservice name, and the responses consisting only of the associated public IP address.

I recognize that this pattern would involve greater latency due to increased external requests. It would also be more difficult to secure, as every microservice is publicly exposed, rather than providing authentication at a single entrypoint. However, it would allow for bandwidth to be distributed much more evenly, and provide a much wider bottleneck, thus making the application much more scalable. Is this a valid strategy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DNS/Public IP based approach not good from a lot of perspectives:

- Higher attack surface area as you have too many exposed points and each need to be protected
- No. of public IPs needed is higher
- You may need more DNS settings with subdomains or domains to be there for these APIs
- A lot of times your APIs will run on a root path but you may want to expose them on a folder path `example.com/service1`, which requires 
  you to use some gateway for the same
- Handling SSL certificates for these public exposures
- Security on a focussed set of nodes vs securing every publically exposed service becomes a very difficult task

Comment: Many of these reasons seem to be essentially the same; 1, 5, and 6 all refer to securing many nodes rather than a single entry point. 4 is not really much of a problem; urls should not be used for any customer-facing UX problem anyways, so if they all have to be subdomains rather than different endpoints of a single domain, that's fine if it means the application is more scalable. Bullet 2 is not much of an issue if its a cloud-enabled system; those ips come with the platform. Bullet 3 is also simple to overcome. So if they can all be secured with a wildcard SSL, what's the problem?

Comment: Also, if the gateway redirects the client to the proper subdomain anyways, e.g. example.com/gateway/microservice1 goes to microservice1.example.com, then the client isn't even really concerned with the subdomain. They access the subdomain via a redirect from the "folder structure" anyways.

Comment: @Nerdizzle, there are multiple ways things can be done and then there usually a more accepted way of doing things. Entry gateways are usually one such accepted way. The extra hop of a gateway vs direct exposure may give you some extra milliseconds, but you have to weigh at what cost. Also in case you are on a very response time critical application, then you may look into these type of solution but otherwise doing this is an overkill

Answer (score 0):

While theoretically it is possible to redirect clients directly to the nodes, there are a few pitfalls.

Security, Certificate and DNS management has been covered by @Tarun

**Issues with High Availability**

DNS's cache the domains vs IP's they serve fairly aggressively because these seldom change. If we use DNS to expose multiple instances of services publicly, and one of the servers goes down, or if we're doing a deployment, DNS's will continue routing the requests to the nodes which are down for a fair amount of time. We have no control over external DNS's and their policies.
Using reverse proxies, we avoid hitting those nodes based on health checks.

Comment: You could still use a reverse proxy for each microservice, but use redirection from the gateway to those reverse proxies. Then this is only an issue if the reverse proxies go down. If that's the case, no strategy will solve this problem. If you can't access the microservice load balancer, you can't access the microservice. You only need a public IP / DNS resolution for each load balancer / reverse proxy, and they shouldn't change anyways.

Comment: Agreed. But you then run into the same bottleneck that you originally spoke of, albeit at a later stage. Also to do Canary deployments etc you might want to bunch a few services behind the same reverse proxy. This grouping quickly escalates into the original problem, which we need to work with anyway.

Comment: If you have service groups that are completely independent of each other and never need to interact with each other, then by all means, partition them completely and navigate to them via redirects.

Comment: That's fair. While the problem, "every request to a microservice is bottlenecked at a reverse proxy," has much less impact than, "every request to the entire application is bottlenecked at a reverse proxy," one way or another you do hit a bottleneck at a reverse proxy, and preventing that can only be done by exposing every node publicly.